# Who are the girls depicted in this scene?

Tags: punchline

From *Punch Line* episode 7, at around 6:35 there's this scene:

[image: Punch Line ep.7 6:35]

There are five girls here. Who are they depicting?

1. Blonde with the green dress.
2. Brunette with the blue dress. Meika?
3. Redhead with the purple dress. Mikatan, probably.
4. Slender brunette with the brown dress.
5. Green haired in the lower right.

Comment: I would think that this is Mikatan plus the other members of She's Mei.

Comment: @senshin She's Mei has around a dozen members. When I return home I can take a Screenshot of a poster on Mikatan's room wall. I think they are the tenants of the boarding house, with a ton of hairdo and makeup. Waiting for someone to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Based on their hairstyles, they seem to be (from left to right) Lovera, Ito (undyed), Mika, Yuta (technically a female), and Meika.